Estimating average closeness centrality of a large graph in python in a reasonable time
I have a large network file (about 7 million nodes and 7 million edges) that i've imported in a networkx graph. I need to estimate its closeness centrality average across all nodes. I've tried implementing the Eppstein-Wang algorithm (which computes the Single-Source-Shortest-Path for a random node k times to produce this estimate). However, for a graph this size this computation needs to happen about 1000 times to produce a sufficiently precise result, which would take me about 10 hours on my machine.
E-W has a complexity of theta(k * m) (where m is the number of nodes).
Are there any other estimation algorithms that have less computational complexity and could get me an acceptable result within, say, around one hour?

Can you use cugraph instead of networkx? There is an example of closeness centrality here: https://github.com/rapidsai/cugraph/blob/5956d4d46a5e7c4b38d553fc0f2d7308e90cd440/notebooks/algorithms/centrality/Centrality.ipynb#L51

thanks for the suggestion, i'm going to try it out! do you think it can improve my running time even if i don't have a GPU?

Probably not, its made for the gpu, but worth a shot anyway, could run it on AWS with a gpu instance? Or ask a friend with a gpu to run it

I'm discouraged from running the computation on other hardware unfortunately. Another solution could be to seek out graph features that are inherently less complex to compute, i've opened another question on the matter

networks used to be one of the slower python graph libraries. You could also try igraph which is probably much faster on this problem. And if you have enough memory, run 10 threads in parallel to get the desired 10x speed up.
